# How can I add one day in a datetime value in R

Tags: r, datetime

How can I add one day in a datetime in R?

```
structure(list(timestamp = structure(1667523601, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Add seconds** If xx is the input then add one day's worth of seconds.  This works because POSIXct is internally expressed in seconds and R does not use leap seconds (although it does have a builtin vector, .leap.seconds, available). No packages are used.

```
xx$timestamp
## [1] "2022-11-04 01:00:01 UTC"

xx$timestamp + 24 * 60 * 60
## [1] "2022-11-05 01:00:01 UTC"
```

**2) POSIXlt** Another way is to convert it to POSIXlt, add one to the mday component and then convert back.  No packages are used.

```
lt <- as.POSIXlt(xx$timestamp)
lt$mday <- lt$mday + 1
as.POSIXct(lt)
## [1] "2022-11-05 01:00:01 UTC"
```

**3) seq** seq with by = "day" can be used.  No packages are used.

```
do.call("c", lapply(xx$timestamp, function(x) seq(x, length = 2, by = "day")[2]))
## [1] "2022-11-05 01:00:01 UTC"
```

If we knew that there was only one element in timestamp it could be simplified to

```
seq(xx$timestamp, length = 2, by = "day")[2]
## [1] "2022-11-05 01:00:01 UTC"
```

**4) lubridate** The lubridate package supports adding days like this:

```
library(lubridate)

xx$timestamp + days(1)
## [1] "2022-11-05 01:00:01 UTC"
```

### Note

The input shown in the question is:

```
xx <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(1667523601, tzone = "UTC", 
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `lubridate`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    timestamp = timestamp %m+% days(1)
  )

# A tibble: 1 × 1
  timestamp          
  <dttm>             
1 2022-11-04 01:00:01
```

Answer (score 1):

With `lubridate` you can add days with  `...+days(1)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dd <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(1667523601, tzone = "UTC", class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

dd |> mutate(timestamp + lubridate::days(1))
#>             timestamp timestamp + lubridate::days(1)
#> 1 2022-11-04 01:00:01            2022-11-05 01:00:01
```